# Force References Heading to Uppercase when calling \bibliography{bib filename}

Tags: sectioning, bibliographies, capitalization

Using `\bibliography{filename}`

when I have

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
```

And

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

before I call: `\bibliography{filename}`

I get the heading "References" in bold. How do I force this heading to show up as 12pt upper case "REFERENCES" ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/9043) I removed the thanks and sign off. That's just the style here, in order to keep questions concise. Thanks is best expressed through upvoting answers that help you.

Comment: The title of the references should be consistent with all other section titles in the paper; I see no reason why it should be different. Please, state if this is needed for some submission style.

Comment: I agree with you, I had to submit a paper to a conference (CTS21012) where their call for paper requirements were rather funky. For the picture-quality version, they released a template and class file that had all of the requirements well defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rename `\refname` contents

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}
```

If you are using `babel` for other languages than USA english, then it must be added to the captions part of `babel` otherwise it will be automatically rewritten

```
\documentclass[UKenglish,... ]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto{\captionsUKenglish}{\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `\refname`?

Comment: @egreg: You are right, `\bibname` is for book and report classes. I will change the answer.

Comment: Here is what worked in my case: 

    `\documentclass[USenglish,10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}`
...
Here is ***main difference*** as pointed out above:

    `\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}`

I didn't have to add `babel` package, but did have to add `USenglish` to the `document class`.  Does this automatically make that heading 12pt font?  Just wondering.

Comment: @Sal Jr: The language options (`USenglish`, etc.) are only nessesary for `babel` and related packages. `USenglish` will not change any default layout or setup values.

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\renewcommand{\refname}{REFERENCES}` *after* `\begin{document}`, it works in any language (it's the easiest way to go).

Otherwise in the preamble, if you're using babel (replacing "danish" for any other language you're using:

```
\addto\captionsdanish{%
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{Indholdsfortegnelse}
```

Source:
https://texfaq.org/FAQ-latexwords

There's another way to do it with `polyglossia`, if you're using xetex (you'll need to load the `etoolbox` package):

```
\gappto\captionslingua{\renewcommand{\chaptername}{Caput}}
```

Where "lingua" is the language whose chapter/header name you're redefining.